# where can I get people to create project with me?

Tags: human-resources

I've almost finished my studies. Actually I am looking for job to get experience but besides this I have a lot of free time. Could you tell me where can I (make relationship with ) find new people who also likes create new games or apps in java/c# and work together?

Comment: http://www.gamedev.net and http://www.google.com

Comment: Likely this question isn't a fit for the Q/A format. It would be a fine question for chat though.

Comment: I will ask, sorry for inconvenience

Comment: For FAQ purposes, linking to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11310/is-there-a-site-where-people-discuss-game-concepts-and-questions-in-general Judging by the answers, it's probably a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at specialized indie game dev forums like [tigsource](http://forums.tigsource.com/index.php). This forum is perfect to meet other game dev and to share some points of view about game dev.

Answer (score 0):

depending on your target (platform/engine/framework) there are full communities of people, and many times there will be a section in these community forums whose sole purpose is "help wanted" (where people either post their skill set requesting a job, or post a job requesting applicants)

for Example

- [Unreal](http://forums.epicgames.com/forums/378-Got-Skills-Looking-for-Talent):
- [Unity](http://forum.unity3d.com/forums/17-Collaboration)
- and others

there are also general forums that are not specific to platform/engine/framework, but at some point that question may come up especially if your posting a job opening.